# Метод delete() удаляет файлы в соседних директориях?

Tags: php, laravel

Почему удаляются файлы в соседних с product_1 директориях, лежащих на одном уровне, product_2, product_3 и т.д.?

```
$files=Storage::disk('products')->files('tmp/product_1');
if(count($files)>0) Storage::disk('products')->delete($files);
```

Comment: Недавно активно пользовался методами Storage, в т.ч. и delete(), в версии 5.8. Каких-либо проблем не заметил. Думаю, у Вас либо в "соседних директориях" жесткие ссылки, либо в коде уровнем выше идет удаление по списку директорий, в т.ч. 'tmp/product_1'.

Comment: У меня сомнения насчет конструкции delete($files). Здесь переменная $files объект или массив. Можно ли так указывать? Там же путь должен быть